# Adding SignalR service as a singleton and then adding redis to it

Tags: asp.net-core, redis, signalr

Hello i have an app up and running using orleans and signalR and i use a HubConnectionBuilder to initialize my SignalRClient like this

```
public async Task<HubConnection> InitSignalRCLient()
    {
        Program.WriteConsole("Starting SignalR Client...");
        var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                logging
                .AddProvider(new LogProvider(Log.logger, new LogProviderConfiguration
                {
                    Category = LogCategory.SignalR,
                    Level = LogLevel.Warning
                }))
            )
            .WithUrl(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SignalRInterface"))
            .Build();
```

And then i add the service as a singleton in the configure service

```
services.AddSingleton(SignalRClient)
```

The problem is now that i want to use redis as a backplane to this and i am having issues adding the redis service to my current way of using SignalR
like this doesn't work

```
services.AddSingleton(SignalRClient).AddStackExchangeRedis();
```

according to the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/redis-backplane?view=aspnetcore-2.2 it wants you to add it like

```
services.AddSignalR().AddStackExchangeRedis("<your_Redis_connection_string>");
```

but that doesn't work with how i use SignalR. Is there anyway to get my implementation to work or anyone got any advice on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add in ConfigureServices this:

```
services.AddDistributedRedisCache(option =>
  {
      option.Configuration = Configuration.GetConnectionString(<your_Redis_connection_string>);
  });

services.AddSignalR().AddStackExchangeRedis(Configuration.GetConnectionString(<your_Redis_connection_string>));
```

Also add this in Configure

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
  {
     routes.MapHub<your_Hub>("/yourHub");
  });
```

And don't forget add `abortConnect=False` in connectionStrings